# Getting generic repository with generic dbContext (multiple dbContext)

Tags: entity-framework, repository, asp.net-core-2.0, repository-pattern

I got lost while building generic repository with entity framework which has multiple contexts in my asp.net core 2 api project.

What I need is to inject my repository to controller without knowing which context it is using.

#### DbContext

```
public interface IDbContext
{
}

public interface IBlogContext : IDbContext
{
}

public interface IBlogLogContext : IDbContext
{
}
```

#### Repository

```
public class EfRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    private readonly IDbContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public EfRepository(IDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    /* other stuff */
}
```

#### Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<BlogContext>(options =>
        {

options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
            .UseLoggerFactory(_logger);
        });
        services.AddDbContext<BlogLogContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(EfRepository<>));

        services.AddScoped<IBlogContext, BlogContext>();
        services.AddScoped<IBlogLogContext, BlogLogContext>();

        services.AddUnitOfWork<BlogContext, BlogLogContext>();

    }
```

#### Controller

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<User> _repository;
    private readonly IAuthorService _authorService;
    private readonly ILogger<UserController> _logger;

    public UserController(IRepository<User> repository, IAuthorService authorService, ILogger<UserController> logger)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _authorService = authorService;
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

When I inject `IRepository<User>` in controller constructor, how .net core DI resolve that `User` is `BlogContext`'s entity, so `IDbContext` should be `BlogContext` inside my `EfRepository` implementation?

Comment: I seem to hear Walter Sobchak "_You are entering a world of pain_"

Comment: Personal opinion: repository pattern won't give you much with EF, except more work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51781877/5779732

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I defined my EfRepository with a DbContext generic argument like this:

```
 public class EfRepository<TDbContext, TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TDbContext : DbContext
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    public EfRepository(IDbContextProvider<TDbContext> dbContextProvider)
    {
    }
}
```

And got DbContext-Entity info like this:

```
//EntityTypeInfo is a class has EntityType & DeclaringType props
private IList<EntityTypeInfo> GetEntityTypeInfos()
{
    var result = new List<EntityTypeInfo>();
    var dbContextTypes = this.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => (typeof(DbContext).IsAssignableFrom(t)));
    foreach (var dbContextType in dbContextTypes)
    {
        result.AddRange(
            from property in dbContextType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            where
                Common.IsAssignableToGenericType(property.PropertyType, typeof(DbSet<>)) &&
                Common.IsAssignableToGenericType(property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0], typeof(IEntity))
            select new EntityTypeInfo(
                property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0],
                property.DeclaringType
                );
    }
    return result;
}
```

So I can add relevant services with EntityTypeInfo list:

```
var entityTypeInfos = GetEntityTypeInfos();
foreach (var entityTypeInfo in entityTypeInfos)
{
    //
    //Add IDbContextProvider and DbContext services Here
    //

    //Add IRepository services like this
    var repositoryInterface =typeof(IRepository<>);
    var repositoryImplementation =typeof(EfRepository<,>);

    var genericRepositoryType = repositoryInterface.MakeGenericType(entityTypeInfo.EntityType);
    if (!Common.IocHasRegister(genericRepositoryType))
    {
        var implRepositoryType = repositoryImplementation.MakeGenericType(entityTypeInfo.DeclaringType, entityTypeInfo.EntityType);

        services.AddScoped(genericRepositoryType, implRepositoryType);
    }
}
```