# How to implement a correct repository pattern in .NET

Tags: .net, repository-pattern, crud

This [article](http://www.matlus.com/a-generic-restful-crud-httpclient/) explains how to create a generic HttpClient class with all the basic CRUD operations. Then it creates a type specific repository for a specific POCO object (Called Member).

What I fail to understand is the need for the MemberReposity class that is returning exactly what the GenericHttpClient class would return for a specific type? Can't I simply rename the GenericHttpClient to GenericReposity and then use this for all of my POCO objects CRUD operations? In another word, why would I need a unique repository for every object if they all only require basic CRUD operations?

I could simply instantiate them on my form like this:

```
private GenericReposity<Customer, int> _customerClient = new GenericReposity<Customer, string>(url, "api/Customers/");
```

and then get a customer this way:

```
_customerClient.GetAsync(5);
```

Am I missing a point here?

---

**UPDATE**

After reading about Anti-Pattern I designed a base repository interface as following:

```
internal interface IGenericRepository<T, in TResourceIdentifier>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetManyAsync();
    Task<T> GetAsync(TResourceIdentifier id);
    Task PutAsync(T model);
    Task<T> PostAsync(T model);
    Task DeleteAsync(TResourceIdentifier id);
}
```

Then I implemented it:

```
public class GenericRepository<T, TResourceIdentifier> : IDisposable, IGenericRepository<T, TResourceIdentifier> 
    where T : class
{
    private bool _disposed;
    protected HttpClientHelper<T, TResourceIdentifier> Client;

    protected GenericRepository(string addressSuffix)
    {
        Client = new HttpClientHelper<T, TResourceIdentifier>(Properties.Settings.Url, addressSuffix);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetManyAsync()
    {
        return await Client.GetManyAsync();
    }

    // All other CRUD methods and dispose
}
```

Then I created custom repository interface for each of my entities. For example:

```
internal interface IOrderRepository : IGenericRepository<Order, int>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetOrderBySomeConditionAsync(string condition );

}
```

And finally, I implemented the custom repository:

```
public class OrderRepository : GenericRepository<Order, int>, IOrderRepository
{
    public OrderRepository(string addressSuffix) : base(addressSuffix)
    {
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetOrderBySomeConditionAsync(string condition)
    {
        //get all the orders (GetManyAsync()) and then returns the ones meeting the condition
    }
}
```

This way I can get all the simple CRUD operations without having to implement them one by one for each entity as well as any custom ones. 
Is this a proper approach? Or is this considered anti-pattern?

Comment: Generic repository is considered an anti-pattern. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51781877/5779732) helps you.

Comment: @AmitJoshi after reading your response in the other post and a few other articles, I updated my post. Can you tell me if this is considered a correct approach in your opinion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new approach (after update) looks great.

With this, you bypass all the drawbacks of generic repository; still taking advantage of code reuse from base generic repository.

Not big deal but consider making all methods in base repository `protected` so that those should be only accessible in concrete repository. Of-course this suggestion can be neglected if all concrete repositories implement that method.

Answer (score 1):

Some day you might want to add things that would be unique per entity type like data validation, or encrypting personal information when the data is at rest.