# Repository Pattern Single Interface in Android

Tags: android, repository-pattern

After studying a couple of blog posts on the topic, I got confused as there were different implementations by different developers but they have all used **single interface for repository**.

Assume, we have following interface for repository

```
interface Repository<T> {
    fun get(): List<T>
    fun save(items: List<T>)
}
```

For a specific implementation of this repository with `T = Users`, `Repository.get()`, downloads some data from sever and cache it.

For another type of object, say `Bundles` I not only need these methods but some additional methods e.g. *querying local database for specific column*.

In that case, I can't understand, **do I need to create a separate interface or add methods to existing single interface**, in which case what should I do with the implementation of new methods in other repositories which do not need these methods? It it must to have same interface for all repositories. Personally, I think, its ok to create multiple interfaces for different repositories as long as I abstract them nicely.

Comment: Note that your question is *very* close to what is covered by the "primarily opinion-based" close vote explanation. I tried to answer your question from a technical standpoint.

Comment: I have discussed pros and cons of generic repository in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51781877/5779732) answer in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I need to create a separate interface or add methods to existing single interface

You can do whatever you like. Android does not know anything about repositories and imposes no restrictions.

In my work, I do not create a generic interface (like the one that you show) in the first place. I cannot think of a project that I worked on where developers created a generic repository interface, either. I am sure that some people do create such an interface, but there is no requirement by the OS for one.

> Personally, I think, its ok to create multiple interfaces for different repositories as long as I abstract them nicely.

You are welcome to do that.

Comment: Gosh! May be the confusion raised from the fact that almost all blog posts created repository for only one use case.

Comment: @mallaudin: Blog posts have their limits. So do book examples. :-)

Comment: Exactly. What I am thinking of, if we really don't want to write same methods in multiple repositories , we can still create a top level interface with generic methods and then create other interfaces for specific repositories. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: @mallaudin: If you find value in doing that, it should be fine. Personally, I am not a fan of creating interfaces for the sake of having interfaces. For a huge, multi-module project, this might be appropriate, to help maintain some amount of isolation between the modules. Or, if there is a pluggable system of repositories, where a consumer might get different implementations, then an interface is appropriate. But "all repositories need interfaces" is overkill, IMHO, for smaller projects where there will only ever be a single implementation of that interface.

Comment: @mallaudin: One exception is if your test code (e.g., mock generator) requires interfaces to work properly. In that case, your interfaces are there to support that particular library.

Comment: Perfect. I do agree with `overkill` statement. Kinda same thoughts on the subject. Thanks for you time @CommonsWare or whoever you are replying under the label of CommonsWare ;)